# Pandas groupby().apply() - returning None from the applied function messes up the results

Tags: python, pandas, data-structures, dataframe

I perform groupby() and apply() on a few data frames with the same structure:

```
d = d.groupby( 'groupby_col', as_index = False ).apply( some_function )
```

For some it works as expected, for some it fails. The way it fails is that the dataframe becomes a series where each element contains just column names. It looks like this:

```
In [18]: d.head()
Out[18]:
groupby_col
134663372801          some_col_1 some_col_2 some_col_3 some_col_4...
134663372802          some_col_1  some_col_2  some_col_3  some_col_4...
134663372803          some_col_1  some_col_2  some_col_3  some_col_4...
134663372804          some_col_1  some_col_2  some_col_3  some_col_4...
134663372805          some_col_1  some_col_2  some_col_3  some_col_4...
dtype: object
```

BTW, the applied function returns either a data frame with a correct number of columns or None.

What might be the reason for this and how to debug it?

Comment: Can you post actual raw data and code including your `some_function` with proof where it returns a Series sometimes and others a DataFrame

Comment: Unfortunately I am not at liberty to do so.

Answer (score 0):

The problem goes away if instead of returning None from the applied function I alway return a frame - replaced

```
if some_condition:
    return
```

with

```
if some_condition:
    return d[:0]        # return the empty frame so that the columns match
```

Comment: This is a basic python fact. You don't need any liberty to tell this.